# Why i have import error mac m1 when I use tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, import, jupyter-notebook, importerror, apple-m1

I have installed tensorflow on my enviroment for mac with m1.
The problem is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/marcovinciguerra/Desktop/ciao.ipynb Cella 1 in <cell line: 5>()
  3 import pandas as pd
  4 import sklearn as sk
  ----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
  6 import platform
  8 print(f"Python Platform: {platform.platform()}")

 File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:443, in <module>
441 _plugin_dir = _os.path.join(_s, 'tensorflow-plugins')
442 if _os.path.exists(_plugin_dir):
--> 443   _ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)
444   # Load Pluggable Device Library
445   _ll.load_pluggable_device_library(_plugin_dir)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py:151, in load_library(library_location)
148     kernel_libraries = [library_location]
150   for lib in kernel_libraries:
 --> 151     py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
153 else:
154   raise OSError(
155       errno.ENOENT,
156       'The file or folder to load kernel libraries from does not exist.',
157       library_location)

 NotFoundError: 
 dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site- 
 packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib, 0x0006): Symbol not found: 
 _OBJC_CLASS_$_MPSGraphRandomOpDescriptor
 Referenced from: 
 /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site- 
  packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib
  Expected in: 
/System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph.framework/Versions/A/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph
```

[image]

I use conda to see all my dependencies installed and all the tensorflow requirements are
installed.

[image]
I followed the following guide: https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-mac-metal-jul-2021.ipynb

What should I do?

Comment: Possibly you have a different MacOS version that it is required.

Answer (score 3):

Very anecdotally, I was having the same issue and I solved it by updating my Mac, from version 12.0.1 to 12.5.1.

Comment: I met the same issue. Following this comment, I just updated my macOS from 12.0.1 to 13.0.1 Ventura, and it's now working. Finally a good reason for me to upgrade...

Comment: Same here, this was resolved when I updated away from 12.0.1 (to 13.3.1 in my case). Agree with @HangChen, sometimes keeping up-to-date will pay off..